# when i press Enter on <textarea> the word counter not show the word

Tags: javascript, html, regex, web, counter

[Codepen project link](https://codepen.io/imbharat420/pen/QWbXeKg?editors=1010)

How i change the regular Expression for count the word which anyone enter the write something on that

```js
(countWords=()=>{
 s = document.getElementById("inputString").value;
 s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
 s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,4}/gi," ");
 s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
 document.getElementById("wordcount").value = s.split(' ').length;

})()
```

```html
<textarea name="inputString" id="inputString" cols="50" rows="4">Text to count</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" name="Convert" value="Count Words" onClick="countWords();"> 
<input name="wordcount" id="wordcount" type="text" value="" size="6">
```

Comment: Yeah, a good regex would do wonders here. The issue with your snippet is that you split by `' '`, but something like `One\nTwo` then counts as one.

Comment: Did my suggestion below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You may strip whitespace from start/end with `trim()` and then split with 1+ whitespace chars:

```
s.trim().split(/\s+/).length
```

Or, you could use a matching approach to count all non-whitespace character chunks:

```
document.getElementById("wordcount").value = s.match(/\S+/g)?.length || 0;
```

JS demo (with optional chaining):

```js
(countWords=()=>{
  s = document.getElementById("inputString").value;
  document.getElementById("wordcount").value = s.match(/\S+/g)?.length || 0;
})()
```

```html
<textarea name="inputString" id="inputString" cols="50" rows="4">Text to count</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" name="Convert" value="Count Words" onClick="countWords();"> 
<input name="wordcount" id="wordcount" type="text" value="" size="6">
```

JS demo (without optional chaining):

```js
(countWords=()=>{
  s = document.getElementById("inputString").value;
  var m =  s.match(/\S+/g);
  document.getElementById("wordcount").value = (m ? m.length : 0);
})()
```

```html
<textarea name="inputString" id="inputString" cols="50" rows="4">Text to count</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" name="Convert" value="Count Words" onClick="countWords();"> 
<input name="wordcount" id="wordcount" type="text" value="" size="6">
```